# c++ vector and sizeof

Tags: c++, vector

This is my first time studying vector in C++. In the code below, I don't understand why the output of the array "sixth" is { 16, 2, 77, 29 }. I think the output should be { 20, 6, 81, 33 }.

```
int myints[] = { 16, 2, 77, 29 };

std::vector<int> sixth(myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int));

for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = sixth.begin(); it != sixth.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << "  " << *it;
```

> output: 16, 2, 77, 29

My calculation:

> std::vector sixth (4, myints + 16 / 4 ); 
> sixth = { myints[0] + 16 / 4, myints[1] + 16 / 4, myints[2] + 16 /
> 4, myints[3] + 16 / 4 }; 
> sixth = { 16 + 4, 2 + 4, 77 + 4, 29 + 4 }; 
> sixth = { 20, 6, 81, 33 };

Comment: Why do you believe all values output should be 4 higher than the values in `myints`? Can you please explain!? The `vector` is initialized with `myints` and then printed out. Of course you get the values that are also in `myints`. Is the `+ sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)` confusing you?

Comment: Your calculation seems to be based on believing the constructor of `std::vector` performs some arithmetic operation on the values passed in? What are you basing this assumption on? What reference did you use that led you to this idea?

Comment: The [`std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you're using is the iterator overload, where you pass a `begin` and `end` iterator. `myints` is the "begin" and `myints  + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)` is the "end". The constructor then copies the values in this iterator range without any modification.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh.....I think I understand 50%...vector<int> a <4, 100> means there are four 100s in the array, like {100, 100, 100, 00} so I was confused on how to understand vector<int> sixth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) ). So this means copy the array from "myints" to "myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)"??

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Since `myints` is an array and not an `int`, what `std::vector` does when integers are passed to its constructor is not relevant to this code.

Comment: You may have overlooked the more readable solution: `std::vector<int> sixth (std::begin(myints), std::end(myints))`. The non-member `std::begin` and `std::end` work on all containers, but also on plain old arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You have misunderstood the arguments completely.
They are iterators - which are pointers, in this case - not "number of elements" and "operation to perform on the elements".

```
std::vector<int> sixth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int));
```

is the same as

```
int* begin = &myints[0]; // Pointer to the first array element
int* end = &myints[4];   // Pointer "one past" the last array element
std::vector<int> sixth (begin, end);
```

and just copies the array elements between `begin` and `end` into the vector.
(This is a very common interface in the standard library. You will see plenty of it. )

(Side note: I think that if you're not familiar with the implicit conversions from arrays to pointers, and the nature of pointer arithmetic, your interpretation makes just as much sense as this.)

Comment: Oh I have less than 15 reputation so I can't upvote your answer..but thanks a lot! But how do you differentiate it from normal vector array like vector<int> a <4, 100>??? Because that means there are four 100s in the array, like { 100, 100, 100, 100}. But in the case above, you said it means vector<int> sixth (begin, end) instead so I'm confused a little still.

Comment: @zzanzzani The [`vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has lots of overloads.

Comment: @zzanzzani If you feel that your question has been answered sufficiently, may I suggest that you accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving exactly as it should.

You are not performing and sort of mathematical operation, but much rather the line `std::vector<int> sixth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );` merely tells your vector where to get it's values from.

It's the same as if you'd write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int); ++i)
  sixth.push_back(myints[i]);
```

What you are doing in that line is calculate the 'end position of the source array' and the return value is a pointer to 'at the end of the array'.

Comment: not exactly the same, but close enough for illustration ;)

Comment: Yes, I know, the other one is more efficient because the sizes are already known and stuff, but as you stated: It's meant to illustrate the point. :)